# equivalent of JdiskReport on Ubuntu

Tags: filemanager, system-info

I have used JDiskReport published by JGoodies to analyse the file size distribution on Windows. I am wondering if there is anything that is an equivalent of JDiskReport for ubuntu.

I ask this not for finding the file sizes on a particular system, I have used a shell script to find all the file sizes, but I would like to understand the file size distribution in a pictorial format. So that it is easy not only for me to understand but it is easy for me to explain this too.

Due to my low reputation points I cannot post a picture, but I am looking for something like the figure 2 in  [this](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/shots_main.htm#bar1) link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jDiskReport is a multi-platform application written in Java. You can download Java version from their [download page](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/index.html), unzip the downloaded zip file and start the application from terminal using

```
java -jar jdiskreport-1.4.0.jar
```

(or create an application launcher if you need to run it often)